# 2008 sqlcmd utility much slower on windows server 2003 than windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am running a set of SQL scripts to create a SQL server 2008 database (schema and static data).  The problem I have is the scripts run in 6 mins on my windows 7 dev machine yet when running on the build server which is windows 2003 the scripts take 40 mins to run through.

I know even 6 minutes is too long but 40 minutes is unacceptable!  Most of the time is in setting up the 100s of thousands of records of static data (scripted from sql server management studio into batches of 1000).

The SQLCMD util was downloaded along with the SQL client tools for SQL server 2008 from this web site: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8824

So my question is:

Is there any known reason why running SQLCMD would be slower on a windows server 2003 machine vs a windows 7 machine?

Comment: On further inspection I am thinking it may be a performance difference b/t the 64bit and 32bit versions?  is it possible the massive difference is related to different versions.   I ran the script on two server 2003 boxes both 32 bit and both ran horrible slow.  I ran the script on a server 2008 64 box and it was as quick as my dev machine.  I would like to know if any else has experienced anything like this ?

Comment: Are you creating new databases/data files/restoring a backup in your script? Tell us more about what your script is doing please.

Comment: Creating a new database from script, see my response to your answer below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you do NOT have [Instant File Initialization](http://www.johnsansom.com/sqlserver-instant-file-initialization) enabled on the server?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply I read the blog post which was an interesting read I hadn't heard of instant file initialization before.

As for you question above I did leave out some detail in the question.

I am creating the database on a shared database server, all the windows machines I ran the test on were running scripts using sqlcmd against the same database server on the same network.  The scripts consist of schema creation scripts (create tables, defaults, indexes etc... and also insert scripts for all static data (90MB worth).  Any other ideas why it is soo much slower on server 2003